# How to access global data array created asynchronously in another function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, asynchronous

As the title says, I just want to access the global array data that I populated in getURLs() in my getSubURLs() function so that I can manipulate the data inside. Can someone let me know how I can do this? Thank you so much ahead of time!!

```
const cheerio = require('cheerio');
const axios = require('axios');

let URL = 'https://toscrape.com';
const urlQueue = [];

const getURLS = async () => {
  await axios
    .get(URL)
    .then((res) => {
      const data = res.data;
      const $ = cheerio.load(data);

      $("a[href^='http']").each((i, elem) => {
        const link = $(elem).attr('href');
        if (urlQueue.indexOf(link) === -1) {
          urlQueue.push(link);
        }
      });
      console.log(urlQueue);
      return urlQueue;
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(`Error fetching and parsing data: `, err);
    });
};

const getSubURLs = async () => {
  // call urlqueue array here after it finishes being created 
}

getURLS();
```

Comment: Why use async functions when you actually need them to wait for eachother?

Comment: Honestly, I'm a noob, and I don't know how to queue that data and use it so I can scrape again. What do you advise that I do?

Comment: I don't know, I'm missing a lot of information about what you're trying to do but based on your example, you don't seem to need async

Comment: I am trying to scrape a website, then queue all urls from that site, and then follow them. In get suburls(), I am going to take that array and loop through them, pulling each of their urls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't mix `async` with `.then` syntax, just `await` the result:

```js
const cheerio = require('cheerio');
const axios = require('axios');

let URL = 'https://toscrape.com';
const urlQueue = [];

const getURLS = async () => {
    try {
        const res = await axios.get(URL);
        const data = res.data;
        const $ = cheerio.load(data);

        $("a[href^='http']").each((i, elem) => {
            const link = $(elem).attr('href');
            if (urlQueue.indexOf(link) === -1) {
                urlQueue.push(link);
            }
        });
        console.log(urlQueue);
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(`Error fetching and parsing data: `, err);
    }
};

// in case there's no top-level await
(async () => {
    await getURLS();

    // do something about urlQueue
})();
```